# Which characters to allow for international usernames and passwords, Django, PostgreSQL

Tags: django, validation, character, utf

I am working on an internationally oriented e-commerce website. Our first target audience is Russian, and Arabic speaking people after that.

Currently I am working on the input validation for the account registration and log in. Now I wonder which characters I should allow in usernames and passwords.

The website is build with Django and Django Rest Framework, using PostgreSQL for the database. Maybe it is useful to add that we use React for the frontend.

Any advice on that? Some (beginner friendly) sources that help a beginner find his way in this area would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the permitted characters at all?

Comment: Well, it's just something that is very new to me. And I simply don't know if I can just let any characters be chosen for the username / password (or for any field for that matter). I can imagine that the software that we are building needs to be prepared to handle all the characters, and that it is not by default. So I am hoping to get some direction on how to approach this. But judging on your comment I guess that I can safely allow any characters?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to just stick with Django's defaults. Django allows any character in a password, and "[unicode] alphanumeric, `_`, `@`, `+`, `.` and `-` characters" [in a username](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username).

That said, it's fine to allow a broader set of characters in the username as well. Some people advocate allowing anything at all. Others are concerned about some of the possibilities that that allows (e.g. distinct usernames that look the same). You can choose whatever rules make sense for your site, but be aware that it's going to be hard to choose rules that allow all the "normal" stuff while eliminating all the "weird" stuff.

StackOverflow itself is a good example. Its [restrictions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344927/2395796) on username characters prevent people from impersonating moderators or interfering with the `@`-mention commenting scheme. Yet the result still allows weird stuff like [invisible usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195798/cannot-reply-to-users-with-usernames-composed-of-non-visible-unicode-character).